# When I boot my Arch Linux the screen simply goes completely black and I can't use it

Tags: boot, arch-linux

One day I turn on my computer and I select Arch in the GRUB, in the screen appears this:

```
Startting systemd-udevd version 252.4-2-arch
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 465547/4587520 files, 13756542/18350080 blocks
And then the screen goes completely black with a prompt at the upper left corner.
```

So far what I have tried is to mount the partition with bootable USB with the Arch installer (which did not give problems, the partitions are fine) start the system I mounted and then update with pacman. It didn't work, so also I tried update packs: dev, linux, base, linux-firmware, with pacstrap, but it didn't work either.

Note: I have no idea of the path of some log file in arch which I could put here for more information, so just tell me and I'll put it here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just X that failed to start. Did you try switching to another virtual terminal with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2-F6</kbd>?

Other than that from the first message you can see that the kernel has loaded successfully and proceeded to systemd initialisation. Which is when something went wrong. This of course doesn't mean that the successful kernel load was with all the modules and configuration flags needed for a functioning system, but is a start.

What error does pacman produce? Do you see anything suspicious in journalctl? Now I see that you only mounted the partition - did you chroot there?

Comment: "Did you try switching to another virtual terminal with": yes, but I can't switch anything. I can't even see the login text interface.

Comment: "did you chroot there?": of course, it's necessary to update with pacman

Comment: "What error does pacman produce?": When the problem started, there was an error with some kernel modules, but I solved it. Now (about a month of not using linux) I just can't update the system throwing me the error "error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
error: could not determine filesystemmount points
error: failed to commit tramsaction (unexpected error)

Comment: I think these lines of kernel in journalctl may say something: "x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS"
"MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details."
"hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS"
"wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found" x4 and 2 very similar errors
"platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2"

and this line of systemd-udevd:
"vtcon1: Process '/usr/lib/system-vconsole-setup' failed with exit code 1."

Comment: Thank you very much.

1. Maybe specify that you also chrooted in the original question, so that I can remove it from the answer. Just to make sure - you used `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash`, right? Is `cd /etc && ln -sf ../proc/self/mounts mtab` of any help?
`

2. SGX and MDS are not relevant in this case, so let's leave them aside for now. You can look up more when you have time/feel curious.

3. The missing mtab and vtcon1 error are what is stopping you from using your system.

Comment: In /etc I already have the link "mtab" to /proc/self/mounts. The error was because I used "chroot" instead of "arch-chroot" hehe. Maybe in a month I forgot some things.

Comment: Man, I solved it :D!! I just installed the LTS kernel version and then booted the system with it, and it simply works! You were so helpfully, whitout you I wouldn't imagine that the problem was in the kernel. Thank you so much.